# calculate the average number C

Tags: c

Uh,I am a biginner in programming..
my code:

```
int main() {
    double a,b,c,result;
    scanf("%f %f %f",&a,&b,&c);
    result = (a+b+c)/3.0;
    printf("%.3f",result);
    return 0;
}
```

then I type:
3 3 3
But I got:  ( 3 is expected)
0.000

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why aren't you scanning your doubles with `%lf`?  You're scanning floats (`%f`) into pointers that are pointing to doubles.

Comment: Do you actually even need `float` or `double` for `a`, `b`, and `c`? That is, are the inputs actually expected to be integers? If so `int` variables with `%d` would be better.

Comment: 王正君, Save time, enable all warnings  to quickly warn about `double a,b,c,result; scanf("%f %f %f",&a,&b,&c);`.  Faster than posting on SO.